# Ansible - Skip a role using a when condition

Tags: ansible

I tried to skip a role using when . Followed this [How to skip role executing in Ansible](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21063159/1839005) and it's working . Wierd thing is the output shows that the role getting executed but none of the steps inside them are. 
For ex :- 
- name : execute this command
  shell : mkdir /test

Then  in the output I see  -name but the shell command is not executed .

Is this how it will work if we skip a role ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is what it will look like when the role is skipped. It will still print the step, and note that it's skipping it.

Comment: I didn't find the note that it's skipping . Any idea how to enable that ?

Comment: Should be enabled by default, but it depends on your version of ansible. As long as it doesn't print "changed" on the host you're acting on (or it prints, "no hosts - skipping"), you're good.